# Template for different data types with similar properties

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to find out if there is any possibility in c++ to have a template for different custom data types with similar properties.

An example: Imagine two data types matrix2x2 and matrix3x3. Both data types consist of a standard array with 2 or 3 elements. Now I want to write a print function which takes a matrix-argument (either matrix2x2 or matrix3x3) and prints the contents depending on how long the internal array is.

Is there a possibility to do this, without writing the print function twice?

I have been searching on the internet a lot about this but I didnt find any information. It might be a duplicate question but I had a hard time looking for answers.

Comment: You can write your own templated print function. Like `template<typename Matrix> void print(const Matrix& m) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class could looks like the following, with a member function to print the matrix:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t M = N>
class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix() 
    { 
        // handle filling here
    }
    void print() const
    {
         for(int i = 0 ; i < N;i++) {
             for(int j = 0; j < M;j++) {
                 std::cout << data[i][j] << " ";
             }
             std::cout << std::endl;
          }

    }


private:
   T data[N][M];
};
```

Or also have a function as follow:

```
template<typename T, std::size_T N, std::size_T M = N>
void print(const Matrix<T,N,M>& mat)
{
    // print ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to make changes to the matrix class, see Vuwox's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56419728/7340043. If not, you can use this:

```
template<typename Matrix>
void printMatrix(const Matrix& m, std::ostream& out = std::cout)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m.height(); i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < m.width(); j++) {
            out << m[i][j];
        }
        out << std::endl;
    }
}
```